# Semantic UI - menu items to next line instead of long horizontal scroll

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Here is my navbar menu code

```js
$(function () {
 $(".dropdown").dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui secondary extra-large menu">
        <a class="item no-background brand" href="/">Brand</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Home</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Products</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Testimonials</a>
        <div class="ui no-background dropdown pointing item">
            Services
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Mobile</div>
                <div class="item">Tablet</div>
                <div class="item">Computer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui dropdown pointing item">
            Other
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Hosting</div>
                <div class="item">Webmail</div>
                <div class="item">DNS</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right item">
            <button class="ui button">Create Account</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right item">
            <button class="ui primary button">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want my menu items which are not appearing show in next line in mobile but it gives me very long horizontal scrolling. If possible i want them to adjust with respect to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stackable menu for that. Howerver, in the documentation is it mentioned that:

> Stackable menus are intended to be used with only simple menu content.
>   Stacked menus will not replicate all additional stylings for vertical
>   menus like adjusting dropdown position.

```js
$(function () {
 $(".dropdown").dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui secondary extra-large stackable menu">
        <a class="item no-background brand" href="/">Brand</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Home</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Products</a>
        <a class="item no-background" href="/">Testimonials</a>
        <div class="ui no-background dropdown pointing item">
            Services
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Mobile</div>
                <div class="item">Tablet</div>
                <div class="item">Computer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui dropdown pointing item">
            Other
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Hosting</div>
                <div class="item">Webmail</div>
                <div class="item">DNS</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right item">
            <button class="ui button">Create Account</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right item">
            <button class="ui primary button">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```